# Why doesn't list.reverse return a list?

Tags: python, string

Here I am try to reverse the string using below logic,

```
st = "This is Ok"
rst = list(st)
rst.reverse()
''.join(s for s in rst)
```

It is working fine, But when I try to following below logic i am getting an error,

```
st = "This is Ok"
''.join(s for s in list(st).reverse())
```

Here is an error,

```
----> 1 ''.join(s for s in list(st).reverse())

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Please any one explain the above process.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with list comprehension.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`list.reverse` is an inplace operation, so it will change the list and return `None`. You should be using `reversed` function, like this

```
"".join(reversed(rst))
```

I would personally recommend using [slicing notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1903116) like this

```
rst[::-1]
```

For example,

```
rst = "cabbage"
print "".join(reversed(rst))   # egabbac
print rst[::-1]                # egabbac
```

Comment: +1 for `reversed( ... )` function. That is exactly what I needed to reverse only one part of my "multi-dimensional array"

Comment: It should be pointed out that the slicing notation will slice the list and return a new list, whereas the `reversed` function returns an iterator. I would prefer opting for the iterator in most cases.

Answer (score 4):

It fails because `lst.reverse()` reverses a list in place and returns `None` (and you cannot iterate over `None`). What you are looking for is (for example) `reversed(lst)` which creates a new list out of `lst` which is reversed.

Note that if you want to reverse a string then you can do that directly (without lists):

```
>>> st = "This is Ok"
>>> st[::-1]
"kO si sihT"
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the following?

```
"".join(s for s in reversed(st))
```

`reversed` returns a reverse iterator. [Documentation is here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed)

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this?

```
[x for x in a[::-1]]

[x for x in reversed(a)]
```

Both works fine, but it's more efficient using [::-1]

```
min(timeit.repeat(lambda: [x for x in a[::-1]]))
```

Out[144]: 0.7925415520003298

```
min(timeit.repeat(lambda: [x for x in reversed(a)]))
```

Out[145]: 0.854458618996432

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful, similar to above answer but returns a list.

```
list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3, 4], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]]
reversed_list = [("|||".join(reversed(list_item))).split('|||') for item in list_of_lists]
```